# how to create font size style guide for app

Tags: android, user-interface

how to create a font-size style guide for an app developer. developer asking separate sizes as per the resolution Like `(Mdpi:10Px, Hdpi:12Px, Xhdpi:14Px)` for each screen. and also in my designing software, there is only "PX", not "sp" but developer asking in "Sp" sizes how can give a style guide.

Comment: perhaps this would be better asked under the ux forum ?

Answer (score 0):

see if this can be usefull you can convert it as below in android
**PX to SP**

```
public static int dpToPx(float dp, Context context) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```